# Jackson maps objects in [ ] but not in { }

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping

I have a rest application and I'm using Jackson to convert objects to Jsons, but I have a problem:

```
public class Stats {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public int stat1;
    public float stat2;
}
```

This method produces a following json:

```
[[8769,"TEST_PRODUCT#2#0",327,8.0],[8809,"TEST_PRODUCT#4#0",345,9.0],[8749,"TEST_PRODUCT#1#0",349,9.0],[8729,"TEST_PRODUCT#0#0",418,10.0],[8789,"TEST_PRODUCT#3#0",430,11.0]]
```

But [ and ] is start_array and end_array tokens, and so it is not correct as I think, because my objects are not arrays, so I think something like this would be correct:

```
[{id: 8769,name:"TEST_PRODUCT#2#0",stat1: 327,stat2: 8.0}, ......]
```

How can I map my List like this?

Comment: Your `topByCompanyBetweenDates` is not interesting here, so you can remove it, but don't you think it would be important to see _how_ you use Jackson to generate the JSON? And which Jackson version do you use?

Comment: I'm using spring MVC without any jackson specific configs(and it uses jackson)

Comment: Oh my bad, then the deleted part might still be important. But anyway, where do you call the conversion to JSON and with which data? What is `State`? Btw: A "pure" Jackson does the conversion correctly.

Comment: Spring calls it after the return is called in my @RestController methods. My data is List<Stats> containing items like: (list item #0)(9207,"TEST_PRODUCT#0#0",141,7.0), etc...

Comment: You could instead of returning `List<Stats>` return `String` and create th JSON yourself: `ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper(); return om.writeValueAsString(repository.getStats(session, new Timestamp(startMs), new Timestamp(endMs), number));`. As a workaround until you know why Springs Jackson works like that.